# Conjunctive and disjunctive normal forms.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) says that $A \lor B$ is in CNF as it can be written as $\mathbf{True} \land (A \lor B)$.

Now it also says that $\lnot (A \lor B)$ is not in CNF. 
According to me we can write it as $\mathbf{True} \land \lnot(A \lor B)$ and it should also be in CNF. 
Even if we expand the brackets within the negation it will be in CNF

So why is it not in CNF ?

Comment: $\lnot (A\lor B)\equiv \lnot A \land \lnot B$ Which is now in CNF

Comment: What the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) says about $A \lor B$ is wrong. $A \lor B$ is in CNF because a CNF is a conjunction of **one** or more disjunctions of literals: by convention, $A \lor B$ is viewed as a "conjunction" of one disjunction of literals. $\lnot (A \lor B)$ is not a disjunction of literals, so it is not in CNF and $\mbox{True} \land \lnot(A \lor B)$ is not in CNF.

Comment: @RobArthan Agreed. Wikipedia puts that very awkwardly.

Comment: I've had a go at correcting the Wikipedia page. I'll be interested to see if my correction gets past the Wikipedia thought police.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An expression is in CNF if it is a conjunction of $1$ or more conjuncts, where each conjunct is a disjunction of $1$ or more disjuncts, where each disjunct is a literal, and where a literal is either an atomic statement or the negation thereof.

$A \lor B$ fits this definition: it can be seen as the conjunction of exactly $1$ conjunct $A \lor B$, which is a disjunction of $2$ disjuncts $A$ and $B$, and $A$ and $B$ are both literals, since they are both atomic.

Note that something like $A$ fits the definition as well: it would be a conjunction of $1$ conjunct $A$ that is a disjunction of $1$ disjunct $A$ that is a literal since it is atomic.

However, there is no way to make $\neg (A \lor B)$ fit this definition, so it is not in CNF. You can immediately tell, because the only way a negation appears in a statement that is in CNF is if it is a negation of an atomic statement.

Comment: Can't we consider ~(A V B) as one conjunct and disjunction of 2 literals as A and B ?

Comment: @Zephyr No, because that would be $A \lor B$.

Comment: ...or negated literals, Bram: $\lnot(A\lor B) = \lnot A \land \lnot B$ is in conjunctive normal form.

Comment: A conjunction of disjuncts, or of literals, or of negated literals.

Comment: @amWhy $\neg A \land \neg B$ is in CNF, but $\neg (A \lor B)$ is not.

Comment: @Bram28, So in a conjunct, we can't have anything outside bracket right ? like having negation outside A V B, that is ~(A V B )

Comment: @Zephyr Well, you can view $\neg (A \lor B)$ as a single conjunct of a conjunction, and you could see that as the single disjunct $\neg (A \lor B)$ of a disjunction, but $\neg (A \lor B)$ is not a literal, and so that's where it fails to be in CNF.  But yes, anytime there is a negation of anything other than an atomic proposition, you know the statement is not in CNF (or DNF)

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the negation inward--negation should only apply to individual variables.  This means you should use DeMorgan's law to do some rewriting.

See:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form

Answer (score 0):

CNF must be AND's of operands that can only be OR's of (1 or more) literals. The example you show is not CNF because is an AND, one of whose operand is a NOT of something not an OR of literals.

Comment: Your first sentence isn't quite right. CNFs are conjunctions (ANDs) of disjunctions (ORs) of **literals**, i.e., variables or negated variables.

Comment: @RobArthan You're right, thanks for pointing that out to me.

Comment: My pleasure! If you correct your answer, I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @RobArthan Edited. No problem, you can leave it there